# AVX-512 floating point comparison and masking

Tags: x86, floating-point, simd, avx2, avx512

I'm not too familiar with SIMD, but I wrote some very simple stuff with AVX earlier. Now I would like to implement some old AVX codes with AVX-512 too.

What I intend to do:

```
// SIZE, LOW_THRESHOLD, HIGH_THRESHOLD and array are defined
// the code works with float data

for ( int index = 0; index < SIZE; ++index )
{
    array[ index ] = LOW_THRESHOLD < array[ index ] && array[ index ] < HIGH_THRESHOLD ? 1.0f : 0.0f;
}
```

What I've done with AVX:

```
const __m256 lowThreshold  = _mm256_set1_ps( LOW_THRESHOLD );
const __m256 highThreshold = _mm256_set1_ps( HIGH_THRESHOLD );
const __m256 trueValue     = _mm256_set1_ps( 1.0f );
const __m256 falseValue    = _mm256_set1_ps( 0.0f );

for ( int index = 0; index < SIZE; index += 8 )
{
    // aligned load
    const __m256 val = _mm256_load_ps( array + index );
    // compare
    const __m256 comp1 = _mm256_cmp_ps( lowThreshold, val , _CMP_LT_OQ );
    const __m256 comp2 = _mm256_cmp_ps( val , highThreshold, _CMP_LT_OQ );
    // AND
    const __m256 mask = _mm256_and_ps( comp1, comp2 );
    // blend
    const __m256 result = _mm256_blendv_ps( falseValue, trueValue, mask );
    // aligned store
    _mm256_store_ps( array + index, result );
}
```

Now I'm stuck at AVX-512.

```
const __m512 lowThreshold  = _mm512_set1_ps( LOW_THRESHOLD );
const __m512 highThreshold = _mm512_set1_ps( HIGH_THRESHOLD );
const __m512 trueValue     = _mm512_set1_ps( 1.0f );
const __m512 falseValue    = _mm512_set1_ps( 0.0f );

for ( int index = 0; index < SIZE; index += 16 )
{
    // aligned load
    const __m512 val = _mm512_load_ps( array + index );

    // the result of the comparison goes into a mask?
    const __mmask16 comp1 = _mm512_cmplt_ps_mask( lowThreshold, val );
    const __mmask16 comp2 = _mm512_cmplt_ps_mask( val, highThreshold );

    // how to use these masks?
}
```

It would be nice to use `__m512 _mm512_and_ps (__m512 a, __m512 b)`, but there are only __mask16 variables after the comparison and I didn't find any _mm512 function such as `_mm256_cmp_ps`. It is probably an easy issue for the more experienced AVX users.
Thanks!

Comment: N.B. if `falseValue` is always `0.0f` you can simply write `const __m256 result = _mm256_and_ps( trueValue, mask );`

Comment: It is 0 in most of the cases, but it can be an arbitrary value actually. But thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you look at the type definition of `__mmask16`, you'll see: `typedef unsigned short __mmask16;`. So you can treat this type like uint16_t and just use '&'.
Then you can use `__m512 _mm512_mask_blend_ps (__mmask16 k, __m512 a, __m512 b)`.

This works perfectly for me:

```c
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define LOW_THRESHOLD 1
#define HIGH_THRESHOLD 3

int main() {
    __m512 lowThreshold  = _mm512_set1_ps( LOW_THRESHOLD );
    __m512 highThreshold = _mm512_set1_ps( HIGH_THRESHOLD );
    __m512 trueValue     = _mm512_set1_ps( 1.0f );
    __m512 falseValue    = _mm512_set1_ps( 0.0f );

    float array[16] = {-5.0f,6.0f,4.0f,1.5f,0.7f,1.0f,1.0f,-5.0f,6.0f,4.0f,1.5f,0.7f,1.0f,1.0f,-5.0f,6.0f};

    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i += 1) {
        printf("%5.1f ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");

    for ( int index = 0; index < 16; index += 16 )
    {
        __m512 val = _mm512_loadu_ps( array + index );
        __mmask16 comp1 = _mm512_cmplt_ps_mask( lowThreshold, val );
        __mmask16 comp2 = _mm512_cmplt_ps_mask( val, highThreshold );
        __mmask16 mask = comp1 & comp2;
        __m512 result = _mm512_mask_blend_ps(mask, falseValue, trueValue);
        _mm512_storeu_ps( array + index, result );
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i += 1) {
        printf("%5.1f ", array[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

As a further optimization, you can use a zero-masked compare-into-mask to AND them for free, like `_mm512_mask_cmplt_ps_mask(comp1, val, highThreshold)`.  A mask bit is 1 only where `comp1` was set and the FP compare is true.

Clang already optimizes the above code to do that; note the `vcmpltps  k1 {k1}, zmm0, dword ptr [rip + .LCPI0_1]{1to16}` in the asm output ([**Godbolt**](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(filename:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:1,lang:___c,selection:(endColumn:38,endLineNumber:37,positionColumn:38,positionLineNumber:37,selectionStartColumn:38,selectionStartLineNumber:37,startColumn:38,startLineNumber:37),source:%27%23include+%3Cimmintrin.h%3E%0A%23include+%3Cstdio.h%3E%0A%0A%23define+LOW_THRESHOLD+1%0A%23define+HIGH_THRESHOLD+3%0A%0Aint+main()+%7B%0A++++__m512+lowThreshold++%3D+_mm512_set1_ps(+LOW_THRESHOLD+)%3B%0A++++__m512+highThreshold+%3D+_mm512_set1_ps(+HIGH_THRESHOLD+)%3B%0A++++__m512+trueValue+++++%3D+_mm512_set1_ps(+1.0f+)%3B%0A++++__m512+falseValue++++%3D+_mm512_set1_ps(+0.0f+)%3B%0A%0A++++float+array%5B16%5D+%3D+%7B-5.0f,6.0f,4.0f,1.5f,0.7f,1.0f,1.0f,-5.0f,6.0f,4.0f,1.5f,0.7f,1.0f,1.0f,-5.0f,6.0f%7D%3B%0A++++asm+volatile(%22nop+%23+array+ready%22+::+%22r%22(array)+:+%22memory%22)%3B+//+stop+it+from+optimizing+away.%0A%23if+0%0A++++for+(int+i+%3D+0%3B+i+%3C+16%3B+i+%2B%3D+1)+%7B%0A++++++++printf(%22%255.1f+%22,+array%5Bi%5D)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++printf(%22%5Cn%22)%3B%0A%23endif%0A%0A++++for+(+int+index+%3D+0%3B+index+%3C+16%3B+index+%2B%3D+16+)%0A++++%7B%0A++++++++__m512+val+%3D+_mm512_loadu_ps(+array+%2B+index+)%3B%0A++++++++__mmask16+comp1+%3D+_mm512_cmplt_ps_mask(+lowThreshold,+val+)%3B%0A++++++++__mmask16+comp2+%3D+_mm512_cmplt_ps_mask(+val,+highThreshold+)%3B%0A++++++++__mmask16+mask+%3D+comp1+%26+comp2%3B%0A++++++++__m512+result+%3D+_mm512_mask_blend_ps(mask,+falseValue,+trueValue)%3B%0A++++++++_mm512_storeu_ps(+array+%2B+index,+result+)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A%23if+0%0A++++for+(int+i+%3D+0%3B+i+%3C+16%3B+i+%2B%3D+1)+%7B%0A++++++++printf(%22%255.1f+%22,+array%5Bi%5D)%3B%0A++++%7D%0A++++printf(%22%5Cn%22)%3B%0A%23endif%0A+++asm+volatile(%22nop+%23+SIMD+loop+done%22+::+%22r%22(array)+:+%22memory%22)%3B+//+stop+it+from+optimizing+away.%0A%7D%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:54.615116661361114,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:cclang1400,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%270%27,trim:%271%27),flagsViewOpen:%271%27,fontScale:14,fontUsePx:%270%27,j:2,lang:___c,libs:!(),options:%27-O3+-march%3Dskylake-avx512%27,selection:(endColumn:73,endLineNumber:15,positionColumn:9,positionLineNumber:15,selectionStartColumn:73,selectionStartLineNumber:15,startColumn:9,startLineNumber:15),source:1,tree:%271%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27x86-64+clang+14.0.0+(C,+Editor+%231,+Compiler+%232)%27,t:%270%27)),header:(),k:45.384883338638886,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4)).  (It's rewriting the same mask register.  And the memory source operand is a broadcast-load.)

`falseValue` is 0.0, so zero-masking can produce it instead of actually needing a constant in a register to blend from.  But there aren't zero-masked stores, only merge-masking, so if we're just storing the result still need a separate instruction to produce the blend result in a register.

But it can just be a zero-masking move, like the `vmovaps zmm0 {k1} {z}, zmm1` clang uses.  So clang's already doing this optimization, as if you'd used `_mm512_maskz_mov_ps(mask, _mm512_set1_ps(1.0f))` in the source. That avoids needing a `set1(0.0)` constant in a register, and might be cheaper than a full blend on some CPUs.

(GCC makes the same optimizations as clang in this case, but [MSVC](https://godbolt.org/z/7jMTqMqc7) uses an actual `kandw` instruction, and `vxorps` + `vblendmps` to blend.)

Comment: Thank you, it's great! The true, false parameters of _mm512_mask_blend_ps seems to be switched, but that's marginal.

Comment: Fixed ! I had a feeling my results made sense but were weird somehow x)

Comment: You can get the masks ANDed for free by doing the 2nd compare with `_mm512_mask_cmplt_ps_mask(comp1, val, highThreshold)`.  That applies zero-masking to the compare operation itself, so an output bit is `1` only where `comp1` was set *and* the FP compare is true.  Masked compare-into-mask looks like `vcmpps k2{k1}, zmm0, zmm1` in the asm.

Comment: `falseValue` is `0.0`, so zero-masking can produce it.  There aren't zero-masked stores, only merge-masking, so I think we still need an instruction to produce the blend result in a register.  But it can just be a zero-masking move, like `vmovaps zmm2{k2}{z}, zmm1`.  That avoids needing a `set1(0.0)` constant in a register, and might be cheaper than a full blend on some CPUs.  But compilers can probably do that for you; at least I'd expect clang will.  Indeed, https://godbolt.org/z/GE43ETqza shows it does.